# How to customize Wordpress Dashboard Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to customize my Wordpress Dashboard based on the user roles. For ADMIN, he has all the menus showing up in his dashboard menu:
[image]

Now I also have a user for whom I want only two menu items to show up, ie. Users and Upload Document, something like:
[image]

I tried Adminimize and Admin Menu Editor, but both doesn't do the intended task. Can anyone please suggest a way/Plugin to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Go on user profile and give permission which you want to do it.

User >> all user >> select user >> and find list of role(this role has some permission.).

Comment: Where do I check the permissions? Let's say if I have another user subscriberAdmin, and when he logs in, he would see only Users and Upload Document options.

Comment: go admin panel and users >> select one user profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following plugin to have control on your admin menu and you can customized it based on your user roles

https://wordpress.org/plugins/client-dash/

Its really easy to use. Just Install it and Go to Settings – >Client Dash. The second tab will be Menus. Go there. Where it says “Select a menu to edit”, click in the dropdown and select the role you would like to customize the admin menu for. Then click on the Select button.

Ensure that “Import role’s existing menu items?” is checked and hit the Create Menu button. This will show a progress bar briefly as the menu that the selected role is currently seeing is imported. This way you don’t have to start from scratch but can easily modify what users with this role are already experiencing.

You can even add and delete menu items.

Hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: Tried it already. It shows the active menus for all the Users but when I make a change, it doesn't show up for that user.